# Dependency injection in spring framework - working

Tags: java, spring

I am learning Spring framework using the online material, and implemented a simple program as below:

I am using the methodology of "Coding to interface" and this is the interface:

```
package com.vipin.math;

public interface MathOperations {

    public int add(int a, int b);
    public int sub(int a, int b);
}
```

One of the implementations that i did:

```
package com.vipin.math;

    public class MathOperationsImpl implements MathOperations {

    public int add(int a, int b) {

        return a+b;
    }

    public int sub(int a, int b) {

        return a-b;
    }
}
```

The main class which depends on this is:

```
package com.vipin.app;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.vipin.math.MathOperations;
import com.vipin.math.MathOperationsImpl;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MathOperations mathOperations;
        ApplicationContext appContext = null;
        appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        mathOperations = appContext.getBean("mathOperationsImpl", MathOperationsImpl.class);
        System.out.println(mathOperations.add(10, 20));
    }
```

Now, since MainApp is dependent on MathOperations (to specific implementing class), and we doing this using getBean() on ApplicationContext.

I tried using @Resource / @Autowire  instead of using getBean(), like this in Main itself:

```
@Resouce("MathOperationsImpl")
MathOperations mathOperations;
```

Also like this:

```
@Autowired()
@Qualifire("MathsRelated")
MathOperations mathOperations;
```

However, i am getting null pointer exception when i am invoking the add() method.

Isn't DI supposed to work in such scenarios?

Any clue would be appreciated.

Here is spring.xml, only relevant portions shown here

```
<beans 

<bean id="mathOperationsImpl" class="com.vipin.math.MathOperationsImpl">
<qualifier value="MathsRelated">
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

Comment: (Is the `@Qualifire` a typo in your question?)

Comment: oh yes it is typo, i am using eclipse IDE, that captures all this.

Comment: show us your spring.xml content.

Answer (score 0):

The auto-wiring will work only if the `Main` class is also managed by Spring container. In other words it should be one of the Component class that can be configured, wired and managed by Spring itself.

Here the `Main` class is used to load the Spring container. Use some other class and define a `bean` in XML or use auto-wiring feature in that class that should be annotated by `@Component` if you are using Auto-discovery feature of Spring.

Comment: How that is possible? Can even main class be managed by Spring?

Comment: I have added more explanation.

Comment: Can't see where is it?

Comment: Look at the duplicate post for in depth detail.